# No leer el ReadLine que esta en el while

Tags: c#

Quiero leer un archivo de texto y cada linea de información me la guarde en una lista

```
 List<String> citys = new List<String>();
```

Use un do while para leer todo lo que esta en el archivo de texto mientras no sea null

```
List<String> citys = new List<String>();
        do
        {
            String txt = Read.ReadLine();
            citys.Add(txt);
        } while (Read.ReadLine()!=null);

        Read.Close();
```

Pero al leer `while (Read.ReadLine()!=null);

Avanza de linea, haciendo que esa linea no la guarde
Por ejemplo:
0 Lo guarda en la lista
1 No lo guarda
2 Lo guarda

Comment: Estas haciendo dos veces readline, por eso...

Comment: Qué ocurre si el fichero está vacío? Es probable que te tire una excepción. Por qué no utilizas un `while` en lugar de un `do while`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes simplificar todo utilizando el **método ReadAllLines** de la **clase File**, de esta forma tu código quedaría como:

```
var txt = File.ReadAllLines(rutaFichero);
```

De esta forma en la **variable txt** se guardará un **arreglo de strings** donde cada elemento de ese arreglo será una línea del fichero, si quieres que sea una lista(aunque en realidad no tiene porque serlo) podrías usar el **método ToList**. Para poder usar la **clase File** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.IO;
```